# How to input characters using Classes and Objects

Tags: java, input, character

I'm making a java program that has to store data using classes and objects, My question is how do input characters like a name ( billy ) into my code.

Here is the class i did.

```
class bank
{
    int AccountID;
    int HolderName;
    double AccountBalance;
}
```

And i'm assigning here

```
    angel.AccountID = 7532;
    angel.HolderName = 753; // angel
    angel.AccountBalance = angelbalance;
```

I know that i can input integers using the following code

```
System.out.println("Set Balance for Angel: ");
    int angelbalance = sc.nextInt();
```

My question is how do i input text/characters in a way (scanner) does with integer

Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Please don't post picture of code; upload it as text

Comment: Oh i'm sorry quite new i will change my post

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean getting the name input using the Scanner object? Because you've imported java.util.Scanner, you can do:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = sc.nextLine();
```

This will read the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (JOptionPane.showInputDialog) and it is easy to use if you want input from user

```
String name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: "));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will try it with mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either call the Scanner.nextLine() method or the Scanner.next() method to store String input such as a name like "Billy". Here is an example below:

```
//You can use the Scanner.next() method or the Scanner.nextLine() method to store Strings
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
String billy = scan.next();
System.out.println("You entered: " + billy);
```

And here is your output:

```
Enter a name: 
Billy
You entered: Billy
```

I'd check out the Scanner documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/class-use/Scanner.html

Comment: Thank you for the information, i will try this also.